# What does i-- do in the if statement in the loop?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

Why do we have to decrement the counter in the snippets below?

This program sorts array from greatest to lowest. Does decrementing have an effect on a loop counter?

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
       if(array[i] < array[i+1]) {
            temp=array[i];
            array[i]=array[i+1];
            array[i+1]=temp;
            i--; // <<== This line
       }
 }
```

Comment: Debug your code, step through it so see why the code is how it is.

Comment: No idea what you're asking...this appears to be a snippet from bubble sort or another sorting algorithm.  The loop is needed to just cover the array being sorted.

Comment: What's with the downvoting? OP wants to know what `i--` is doing there. It is a good question, because `i--` can be safely dropped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dasblinkenlight already said, the `i--` statement is unnecessary, but that's not all. The `i--` has a purpose, but since the programmer made a mistake, the *sorting algorithm* doesn't work. Let me explain:

The algorithm goes over an array and exchanges two numbers if they are in the wrong order. If two numbers are exchanged, the algorithm has to go **back one step** because the bigger number might be even bigger than the number before. Example:

```
[7  3  11  2  3  5  6  5]
```

First, 7 and 3 are compared. As they already are in the right order, the algorithm proceeds to 3 and 11. These are exchanged, so the new order is

```
[7  11  3  2  3  5  6  5]
```

Now the algorithm has to go back to campare 7 and 11, because 11 should be the first number. That's why there's `i--` in the code. What the programmer forgot is that **i is incremented afterwards**, so in the next iteration i has the same value as before. To make it work, you'd have to **decrement i by 2**. This means that you have to check if i is negative.

Here's the working code:

```
int temp;
for (int i = 0; i < array.length-1; i++) {
    // If i is negative, this should be skipped.
    if (i != -1 && array[i] < array[i+1]) {
        temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[i+1];
        array[i+1] = temp;
        i -= 2;
    }
}
```

Now the array is sorted properly: `[11  7  6  5  5  3  3  2]`

Answer (score 4):

If you suspect that decrementing `i` in the `if` is unnecessary, you are right: it can be safely removed.

The reason the author of the code decremented `i` in the `if` statement was to "undo" the effect of the increment in the loop header, in case additional swaps are required. However, the condition guarantees that the next time around the `if` is going to fail, so it is safe to drop the decrement. For example, if you just swapped 2 and 5 because `2 < 5`, you are *not* going to swap 5 and 2 back, so it is safe to let the loop move on to the next index.

Answer (score 0):

This is required to keep iterating all the items using the Bubble sort algorithm. What do you want to understand here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be use less. If you array contains {1, 2, 3}, the execution will be as following:

> First loop: i=0
>
> > > array[0] < array[1] >> 1 < 2
> > >
> > > temp = 1, array[0] = 2, array[1] = 1, i=0
>
> Second loop: i=0

This caused extra loop which will increase the running time of your code. It's better to use one of the popular sorting algorithm to have best result.